# ionic 2 how to use constants variable's declare in index.html?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I creating a android app in ionic 2. I declare a variable in script tag in   index.html. this constant value i want to use in ionic 2 pages and providers code. i pasted my code below. thanks in advance...

**index.html**

```html
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Ionic</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">

      <link ios-href="build/css/app.ios.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link md-href="build/css/app.md.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link wp-href="build/css/app.wp.css" rel="stylesheet">  
    </head>
    <body>

      <ion-app></ion-app>

      <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
      <script src="cordova.js"></script>

      <script src="build/js/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Zone.js and Reflect-metadata  -->
      <script src="build/js/Reflect.js"></script>
      <script src="build/js/zone.js"></script>
      <!-- the bundle which is built from the app's source code -->
      <script src="build/js/app.bundle.js"></script>

    <script type=​"text/​javascript">​
       BASE_APP_URL="www.google.com";
    </script>​
    </body>
    </html>
```

**item-details.ts**

```ts
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    import {NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
    @Component({
      templateUrl: 'build/pages/item-details/item-details.html'
    })
    export class ItemDetailsPage {
      selectedItem: any;

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, navParams: NavParams) {
                this.selectedItem = navParams.get('item');
                console.log(BASE_APP_URL);
         <!---it gives an error that name
          Error TS2304: Cannot find    name 'BASE_APP_URL'. -->                                 
          }
        }
```

Comment: The proper way to do this is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38937503/where-to-save-settings-like-api-url-in-ionic2-app/38940262#38940262).

Answer (score 1):

Even though a better way to handle static settings in an Ionic app would be the one in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38937503/where-to-save-settings-like-api-url-in-ionic2-app/38940262#38940262), you can make your code work by:

1. Including the script with your variable **before** the `<script src="build/js/app.bundle.js"></script>` because that's where you're going to use it.
2. Declaring that variable as part of the `window` object implicitly.

   ```
   <!-- Your variable -->
   <script type=​"text/​javascript">​
       window.BASE_APP_URL="www.google.com";
   </script>​

   <!-- the bundle which is built from the app's source code -->
   <script src="build/js/app.bundle.js"></script>
   ```

And then in your code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/item-details/item-details.html'
})
export class ItemDetailsPage {
  selectedItem: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, navParams: NavParams) {
    this.selectedItem = navParams.get('item');
    console.log(window.BASE_APP_URL);                    
  }
}
```

That being said, **I still recommend [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38937503/where-to-save-settings-like-api-url-in-ionic2-app/38940262#38940262) when handling static settings in any Ionic 2 app.**

Comment: thanks for reply @sebaferreras!! i used second approch...and it works..